# Method .find() is not a function at Object.<anonymous>?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, find

I am new to Javascript and I struggle with arrays and objects. I am trying to find a value/attribute of a JSON file using the method find. This is the data on the JSON file named "data":

```
{
    "one": {
        "color": "green",
        "amount": 1
    },
    "two": {
        "color": "green",
        "amount": 1
    }
}
```

Then I use this code to execute the method find to get the information that in this case is the number "one".

```
var data = fs.readFileSync("data.json");
var pData = JSON.parse(data);

var isOne = "one";
var match = pData.find(nmb => {
    if (isOne === nmb) {
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

As the code start to run the, I get an error called "pData.find() is not a function at Object.". I tried to stringify the data and still can't access the attribute "one".

Comment: find works on an array not an object

Comment: Therefore, I should put the Object as a .key to get an array right?

Comment: Just use `var match = pData[isOne];`

Comment: That didn’t come thru my mind. It even reduces the length on the code! Just in case the data was an actual array instead of an object the code would work right?